# jquery on input not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a video control slider and not sure why this event is not firing.

jquery:

```
$(document).on('input', '.volume-bar', function() {
    const video = $(this).closest('.video-container').children('video').get(0);
    alert($(this).value());
    video.volume = $(this).value();
})
```

html:

```
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 video-container px-0">
    <video id="rogueVideo" width="100%" poster="images/posters/rogue.jpg">
        <source src="videos/rogue.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="video-controls">
        <button class="play-pause btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-1" type="button"><i class="fas fa-play fa-fw"></i></button>
        <input class="seek-bar w-100 mr-1" type="range" value="0">
        <button class="mute btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-1" type="button"><i class="fas fa-volume-off fa-fw"></i></button>
        <input class="volume-bar w-25 mr-1" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
        <button class="full-screen btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-1" type="button"><i class="fas fa-expand fa-fw"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

it's not getting the event because I never see the alert

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20857620/3385827

Comment: i think you have the parameters for jquery on wrong. which is why the event is not firing for you. 
first parameter is the event type (http://api.jquery.com/on/) which in your situation is probably 'change'.
have you tried $(document).on('change', 'input.volume-bar', function() 
?

Comment: @HenryLu yea, I just tried that and still not triggering and the event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(function(){
    $('.volume-bar').on('input',function() {
       var video = $(this).closest('.video-container').children('video').first();
       alert($(this).val());
       video.prop('volume',$(this).val());
    });
});
```

you change also use the change event instead of input
video.volume.

Comment: thanks I at least have the event firing now, but it doesn't seem to be effecting the video volume.

Comment: Edited my answer video.prop('volume',$(this).val()); try it

Answer (score 2):

You should change to `$(document).on('change', '.volume-bar', function() {` and in jQuery it's `$(this).val()` not `$(this).value()`

```js
$(document).on('change', '.volume-bar', function() {
    const video = $(this).closest('.video-container').children('video').get(0);
    alert($(this).val());
    video.volume = $(this).val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 video-container px-0">
    <video id="rogueVideo" width="100%" poster="images/posters/rogue.jpg">
        <source src="videos/rogue.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="video-controls">
        <button class="play-pause btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-1" type="button"><i class="fas fa-play fa-fw"></i></button>
        <input class="seek-bar w-100 mr-1" type="range" value="0">
        <button class="mute btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-1" type="button"><i class="fas fa-volume-off fa-fw"></i></button>
        <input class="volume-bar w-25 mr-1" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
        <button class="full-screen btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-1" type="button"><i class="fas fa-expand fa-fw"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not a matter of what "you like" changing the event has nothing to do with the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

the `input` event works just fine, but [Mozilla does recommend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) using `change` instead since `input`'s implementation is inconsistent.

Also, always check the console. `$.value()` is not a function.

```js
$(document).on('input', '.volume-bar', function() {
  const video = $(this).closest('.video-container').children('video').get(0);
  alert($(this).val());
  video.volume = $(this).val();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 video-container px-0">
  <video id="rogueVideo" width="100%" poster="images/posters/rogue.jpg">
        <source src="videos/rogue.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  <div class="video-controls">
    <button class="play-pause btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-1" type="button"><i class="fas fa-play fa-fw"></i></button>
    <input class="seek-bar w-100 mr-1" type="range" value="0">
    <button class="mute btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-1" type="button"><i class="fas fa-volume-off fa-fw"></i></button>
    <input class="volume-bar w-25 mr-1" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
    <button class="full-screen btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-1" type="button"><i class="fas fa-expand fa-fw"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @caramba - they're the same thing.

Comment: @caramba - that's exactly why you shouldnt arbitrarily change shit for no reason. does the volume on your car stero only change when you remove your hand from the knob? that's bad ux.